# .remove is not a function while deleting object

Tags: javascript, mern

```
export const deleteCourse = catchAsyncError(async (req, res, next) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    const course = await Course.findById(id);

    if (!course) return next(new ErrorHandler("Course not found", 404));

    await cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(course.poster.public_id);

    for (let i = 0; i < course.lectures.length; i++) {
        const singleLecture = course.lectures[i];
        await cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(singleLecture.video.public_id, {
            resource_type: "video",
        });
    }

    await course.remove(); //error occurs here

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "Course Deleted Successfully",
    });
});
```

i have created a course and expecting to delete that but it says .remove is not a function

Comment: `remove` has been removed from the libary. Use `findByIdAndDelete` or `findByIdAndRemove`.

Answer (score 1):

could you please try that:

```
await Course.deleteOne({ _id: id});
```